# Set property with value based on maxium value of this property in all nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, max, nodes

I would like to set 'id' property for each 'Sc' node which doesn't contain that property. Value for each property should be greater by 1 than actual maximal value of this property in all 'Sc' nodes. How to achieve that? I came up with this query, but using MAX isn't allowed with SET.

```
MATCH p=(s:Sc)
WHERE NOT exists(s.id)
FOREACH(skl in nodes(p) | SET skl.id = MAX(toInteger(s.id))+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Collect all sc without id
> 2. For each sc, create a sequence of numbers from 1..n
> 3. Then set the value of each node sc.id equals maxValue + row number

```
MATCH (sc:Sc) WHERE EXISTS(sc.id)
WITH max(sc.id) AS maxValue
MATCH (s:Sc) WHERE NOT EXISTS(s.id)
WITH maxValue, collect(s) as scs
UNWIND range(1, size(scs)) as row
SET (scs[row-1]).id = maxValue+row

Sample result:
╒═══════════════════╕
│"Sc"               │
╞═══════════════════╡
│{"id":1}           │
├───────────────────┤
│{"id":2}           │
├───────────────────┤
│{"name":"a","id":3}│
├───────────────────┤
│{"name":"b","id":4}│
├───────────────────┤
│{"name":"c","id":5}│
└───────────────────┘
```

Comment: This is extalcly what I needed. So basically UNWIND is iterating through list prepared with range() function and executing SET in each iteration? Thank You for Your help.

Comment: Yes, UNWIND is like a for loop and it is iterating on each number from 1 to n. You can remove the last line and put RETURN * to see it. Good luck!

Comment: Unless you *really* ***need*** them to be sequential, I might suggest using [apoc.uuid](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/uuid/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
MATCH (s:Sc)
WHERE EXISTS(s.id)
WITH max(s.id) AS maxValue
MATCH (s:Sc)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(s.id)
SET s.id = maxValue + 1
```

Comment: I had 46 nodes with 'id' property and 3 without it. After this query those 3 nodes (obviously) received 'id' property, but each of them contain '47' value. I would like every succeding node to contain 'id' greater by 1 than preceding node (in this particular situation 47, 48, 49). Thank You for Your reply.